# how to add whatsapp web js pkg on vercel in nodejs

Tags: node.js, whatsapp

how to apply this command in vercel because i am useing whatsapp web js pkg in nodejs and vercel gives me error of serverless function, I believe by doing this command my problem will be solved[image]

i add whatsapp webjs pkg in nodejs and deployed it on vercel but becauuse whatsapp webjs uses pupetteer so vercel gives me error
in  whatsapp webjs documentation no hui command is given , i dont know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

As you may know, Vercel is a serverless deployment platform, and running Puppeteer (which is used by whatsapp-web.js for headless browser automation) directly on Vercel might be challenging due to some limitations and restrictions.

Try using automation package like baileys which connect direct through socket.
[Baileys](https://github.com/WhiskeySockets/Baileys)

```js
import makeWASocket, { DisconnectReason } from '@whiskeysockets/baileys'
import { Boom } from '@hapi/boom'

async function connectToWhatsApp () {
    const sock = makeWASocket({
        // can provide additional config here
        printQRInTerminal: true
    })
    sock.ev.on('connection.update', (update) => {
        const { connection, lastDisconnect } = update
        if(connection === 'close') {
            const shouldReconnect = (lastDisconnect.error as Boom)?.output?.statusCode !== DisconnectReason.loggedOut
            console.log('connection closed due to ', lastDisconnect.error, ', reconnecting ', shouldReconnect)
            // reconnect if not logged out
            if(shouldReconnect) {
                connectToWhatsApp()
            }
        } else if(connection === 'open') {
            console.log('opened connection')
        }
    })
    sock.ev.on('messages.upsert', m => {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(m, undefined, 2))

        console.log('replying to', m.messages[0].key.remoteJid)
        await sock.sendMessage(m.messages[0].key.remoteJid!, { text: 'Hello there!' })
    })
}
// run in main file
connectToWhatsApp()
```